# How to update gzip without internet in SUSE?

Tags: linux, suse

We have an old server which is running SUSE SLES10 SP2 x86_64. The server is not connected to internet and we need to update the gzip to a latest version. I am not sure how I can update it. I tried to download the gzip rpm but it need dependencies and those dependencies has other dependencies. Is there a way by which I can download all this and sftp it to the server and from there I update the gzip ?

Comment: SLES10 is ancient, the support [ended completely](https://www.suse.com/lifecycle/) as far as in 31 Jul 2016 for SP4, and even further 11 Apr 2010 for your SP2. Better think about updating the release.

Comment: Unfortunately at this stage i can not upgrade the server